# How can I change the Detail Title section?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

I have a Xamarin Forms application, and the only plaftorm it supports is UWP. I use Master-Detail architecture. I understand how I can change the Title text of the Detail page, but I need to change e.g. height of the Title pane and its background color. I guess it should be done on the MySolution.UWP project, but don't know how to approach this. I don't even know what I should change, TopCommandBarArea, or CommandBar, or LayoutRoot etc.

Here is some of my code from the shared project:

```
    private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.SelectedItem as MainMDPageMenuItem;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        item.ItemBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#006c89");
        if (PreviouslySelectedItem != null)
        {
            PreviouslySelectedItem.ItemBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#00a8d5");
        }

        var page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType);
        page.Title = item.Title;

        Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
        IsPresented = false;

        MasterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;

        PreviouslySelectedItem = item;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the Title bar background color, add below snippet in your `App.Xaml` which is in Xamarin Forms Project:

```
 <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
                <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor"
                        Value="Maroon"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BarTextColor"
                        Value="Violet"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

And to change the Font Attributes, add below code snippet in your UWP project `App.Xaml`

```
<Application.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style x:Key="TitleTextBlockStyle"
                       BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                       TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                            Value="SemiLight" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize"
                            Value="36" />
                    <Setter Property="OpticalMarginAlignment"
                            Value="TrimSideBearings" />
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
 </Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you, the color changing works well! But how can I set the height of the Navigation Bar?

Comment: @DavidShochet Please check out [this](http://lukealderton.com/blog/posts/2017/january/replacing-the-xamarin-headernavigation-bar-with-a-custom-viewtemplate/) article if that helps.